# Convert seconds to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime

I am new to PostgreSQL sql and now working on an already existing database.  I have a column called value in a table and it contains datetime stamp in seconds.  So I am looking for way I can convert those seconds to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in a Postgres database.  I tried the following:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR('1444646136079 second'::interval, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
```

> 1444646136079 is the value I would like to convert
>   But I am getting the following error:
>
> ERROR:  interval field value out of range: "1444646136079 second"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An `interval` is not a "timestamp".

The `to_timestamp()` function accepts seconds as an input and can convert that to a proper timestamp. I believe your 1444646136079 is in fact **milli** seconds, not seconds:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp(1444646136079 / 1000), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
```

returns:

```
2015-10-12 12:35:36
```

Comment: For what an `interval` actually is, see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

**You can try it too**-

```
select to_date(to_timestamp(1344646136069 / 1000)::TEXT, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS');

select to_date(to_timestamp(1344646136069 / 1000)::TEXT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```

**Output**:

```
11.08.2012 00:00:00
11.08.2012 00:00:00
```