# Postgres equivalent of the Timezonedb Mysql query

Tags: mysql, postgresql, timezonedb

I was trying to use the [Timezone DB](https://timezonedb.com/download) in psql which was created in MySql. I have ported the data by manually querying and inserting it into psql via node script. Now what I need is the equivalent psql query of the below query. Since some of the functions in Mysql are not found in psql below query won't work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Definition for the three tables used are

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `country`;
CREATE TABLE `country` (
    `country_code` CHAR(2) NULL,
    `country_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    INDEX `idx_country_code` (`country_code`)
) COLLATE='utf8_bin' ENGINE=MyISAM;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'country.csv' INTO TABLE `country` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `timezone`;
CREATE TABLE `timezone` (
    `zone_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `abbreviation` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    `time_start` INT NOT NULL,
    `gmt_offset` INT NOT NULL,
    `dst` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `idx_zone_id` (`zone_id`),
    INDEX `idx_time_start` (`time_start`)
) COLLATE='utf8_bin' ENGINE=MyISAM;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'timezone.csv' INTO TABLE `timezone` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `zone`;
CREATE TABLE `zone` (
    `zone_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `zone_name` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`zone_id`),
    INDEX `idx_zone_name` (`zone_name`)
) COLLATE='utf8_bin' ENGINE=MyISAM;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'zone.csv' INTO TABLE `zone` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Query for displaying the local timezone in Mysql:

```
    SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) + tz.gmt_offset, '%a, %d %b %Y, %H:%i:%s') AS local_time
FROM `timezone` tz JOIN `zone` z
ON tz.zone_id=z.zone_id
WHERE tz.time_start <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) AND z.zone_name='America/Los_Angeles'
ORDER BY tz.time_start DESC LIMIT 1;
```

What will be the equivalent in Psql?

**This is what I have tried so far. But it is not correct. It shows a difference of +5.30 which is our timezone Kolkata.**

```
SELECT to_timestamp(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC') + tz.gmt_offset) AS local_time
FROM tbl_timezones tz JOIN tbl_zones z
ON tz.zone_id=z.id
WHERE tz.time_start <= (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC') ) AND z.zone_name='America/Los_Angeles'
ORDER BY tz.time_start DESC LIMIT 1;
```

> Please note the field names are not exactly the same.

The result I get is `"2017-12-21 10:38:29.301579+05:30"` where the actual time when checked in Google is

```
5:08 AM
Thursday, 21 December 2017 (GMT-8)
Time in Los Angeles, CA, USA
```

Comment: You'll have to tell us the definition and semantics of `timezone` and `zone`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Added the table definitions now.

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of `timezone.gmt_offset` and `timezone.time_start`? What is the value you want to calculate with the query?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Please have a look at their original website https://timezonedb.com/download It works perfectly in Mysql. I don't know much about the internals of this. As we have an existing app in Postgres we need to use it there.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to wait for someone who either knows timezonedb or is willing to do the legwork for you. I have added a "timezonedb" tag for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have convert to postgres version:

Original from timezonedb.com

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) + tz.gmt_offset, '%a, %d %b %Y, %H:%i:%s') AS local_time
FROM `timezone` tz JOIN `zone` z
ON tz.zone_id=z.zone_id
WHERE tz.time_start <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) AND z.zone_name='Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'
ORDER BY tz.time_start DESC LIMIT 1;
```

My postgres query:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(to_timestamp(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timezone('UTC', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)::timestamptz) + tz.gmt_offset), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') AS local_time
FROM timezone tz JOIN zone z
ON tz.zone_id=z.zone_id
WHERE tz.time_start <= (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timezone('UTC', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)::timestamptz ) ) AND z.zone_name='Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'
ORDER BY tz.time_start DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Reference:

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276622/2552249

[2] https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29